# How can i Support edges with Subsurf Modifier on a Concave shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edges, topology

I have tried everything,
from Supporting edge loops to creasing and Baveling.
Shrinkwrapping.

and even creating the Object flat and then bend it with Lattice.
But no metter what i tried its alawys ends up with some sort of Deform or  a Pinch.
and its seems to be a reoccurring problem when i ever i have something like in the following picture.

The Question is, how can i solve this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please show the kind of object you're trying to achieve? Do you mean for example the angle of an L shape?

Comment: IM trying to round up the edges but keeping the surfaces Flat

https://imgur.com/a/Jow91YY

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier with more edge loops but it seems to work fine like this.

[image]

As the additional edge loops tend to break the circle shape I created a circle to use it as a guide in order to keep the cylinder circular.

[image]

Comment: its almost the shape i wanted to create.
tough i want the upper part to not be as Smooth as well.

https://imgur.com/R0WrrKK

also. what do u mean you brought back the Circular Shape?!

how excactly, 

i tried already using Shrinkwrap. but as i said already, i didnt do much good?

Comment: please show a reference picture as early as possible, it's very hard to guess what you want  ;)   "i want the upper part to not be as Smooth as well", what part of the upper part? The upper part of my object isn't smooth... Try to make a drawing of the final object for example

Comment: I posted a link with an image as a refference. at the same comment as i said it, please pay attention to, seriusly its incredibly frustrating when i need to repeat myself,                      this how u did it https://imgur.com/AMVlPDU

this is how is a crude version of what im trying to achive:
https://imgur.com/R0WrrKK

Comment: Well actually you need to repeat yourself because, maybe you don't realize, but what you ask is not clear at all, you show a round shape but in the same time you say that "i want the upper part to NOT be as Smooth as well", so is it supposed to be smooth or not smooth? People can't guess by themselves what you're the only one to know. Ok I'll give a try with smooth angle

Comment: plus your initial question was very vague and I needed to ask questions and to edit your post...

Comment: I sent u an image.
That reffering to the excact part of the model and how its differ then yours.
u had an angel on this part while the shape im trting to create is more concave.
im pretty sure its pretty easy to understand what i meant.
Any way I did a video screen cupture showing overall what I tried to do
and demonstrated my problems
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzncHcui3pA

Comment: nothing in your initial question could let us guess that's what you wanted, it would have been easy to DRAW your shape, but I've edited my answer, please check

Comment: if u need to understand what i said its one thing:
but when u ask me for a refference after i gave i already did posted a link to an image as a refference it comes off as a waiste of time cuse u asking to give u something i provided.

fact of the metter asside from this one bit part of the mesh that was still angular in ur version. the result u got is excactly what i was trying to create. 
so its sounds like u did understood what i said.

Regardless of all that: i do apprichiate the time u have invested and tried to help me with it. and i do apprihchiate the help. so thank you very much!

Comment: your first question was not clear at all, the image you gave afterwards was not explicite at all, and you asked for contradictory things (smooth and not smooth)... you must put yourself in the shoes of people reading questions, you know what you want but they can't guess... anyway nice to see that this time I succeeded  ;)

Comment: Also, it would have made the things easier if I used more vertices for the central cylinder, but I wanted to keep low in vertices to see if it was possible

Comment: someone else told me the same thing
about the topo density.
so maybe it is the topo densitiy,

but i do wish to keep the denisity as low as possible so thank you!

Comment: BTW what did u when u said "you borught back the circulat shape"?

Comment: to make sure that my inner cylinder was a circle, I created a new circle and made sure my cylinder was following the shape of this circle. If the cylinder was a 16 (or 32) vertex circle it would have made the things much easier as I would not have used any additional vertex that would have broken the circular shape (the additional vertices that I had to create here to sharpen the edges), but it's always interesting to test what you can do with the minimum amount of vertices